# HTML2Canvas with Cron

Tags: javascript, cron, html2canvas

HTML2Canvas not working when you curl the page to create an image.

I created the following code to create a canvas and when you open the webpage it will create an image from the specified div and save it to the server as a png.

But when I try to use CURL commands to open the page. It does not have any errors but the html2canvas does not make any images to the server.

But when I open the html url with my browser it works correctly.

```js
< div style = "display:flex; flex-direction:row;" >
    < div id = "flex-container"
style = "height:786px;width:1024px;" > < /div> < /div> < script >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function capture_details() {
            html2canvas(document.querySelector('#flex-container'), {
                    scale: 1
                })
                .then(function(canvas) {
                    console.log(canvas);
                    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                    $.ajax({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        },
                        url: '{{url('
                        dashboard_c1_test / save_c1_image ')}}',
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {
                            base64data: imgData
                        }
                    });
                });
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '{{url('
            dashboard_c1 / get_data_c1 ')}}',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
                for (let entry in data) {
                    $("#flex-container").append(
                        '<div style="text-align:left; width:80%;">' + '<h2  class="font_rule">' + data[entry].anlass + '</h2>' + '<h2  class="font_rule">' + data[entry].veranstalter + '</h2>' + '<h2  class="font_rule" style="font-style:normal;font-variant:small-caps;font-weight:bold;">' + data[entry].raum_name + '</h2>' + '</div>'
                    );
                }
                capture_details();
            }
        });
    }); < /script> < script src = "{{asset('/public/js/html2canvas.js')}}" > < /script>
```

I was expecting that when I use the Curl command to the url it will make a png everytime but when I use curl it does not make any png.